# page order in UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, swift3, uipageviewcontroller, uipagecontrol

I am using `UIPageViewController` so when a user swipes down they can view their profile information; however, it is currently ordered so that user must swipe up.

What particular code effects the order of presentation in `UIPageViewController`?

Comment: Are you doing it programmatically or via Storyboard? Could you share some code?

Comment: if you have [`setViewControllers:direction:animated:completion:`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uipageviewcontroller/1614087-setviewcontrollers) implemented, can you show what that code looks like?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann i apologize for late reply but I was doing programatically, I was able to achieve by setting main VC in index to 2nd value